# No route matches [POST] for update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think the solution to this question should be obvious, but I tried out every suggested solution in all the similar questions but could not get my problem solved

I have a rails api project, that I needed to build a view for. I have a controller called password_resets_controller with functions edit and update.

My view for edit works fine, except that when the form is submitted, I get the following error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/password_resets/Ho5kqU9qvuc0LTiuotOYQw"
```

The reason this is very weird is that the request parameters are:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"WksU8TIWTJ2+WmqpKTiaaETWLD9hhFP1pzxQJAU73g51Cij6GTL0PZbLf8BuJI2l1HqHuNhOZwMs+qSVQxiPtQ==",
 "email"=>"whatever@example.com",
 "user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Update password"}
```

which shows that the method is patch or put alright and not post

The relevant part in the view file is:

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: password_reset_path(params[:id]), method: :put) do |f| %>

  <%= hidden_field_tag :email, @user.email %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit "Update password", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I know that the path I have is fine, as in routes I have:

```
resources :password_resets, only: [:create, :edit, :update]
```

And the routes that are dumped while posting show the is a correct path (this is a copy and paste from the table, so excuse the skewed result):

> password_reset_path   PATCH   /password_resets/:id(.:format)
>   password_resets#update
>
> PUT   /password_resets/:id(.:format)   password_resets#update

In the controller I have function alright.

```
def update 
end
```

I just want the code to reach this function but I'm stuck in the form submission. At first my form was without the `:method`. Adding it did not make the form work though.
What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Did You try to set `method: :patch` ?

Comment: Yes, same error unfortunately

Comment: Passing `@user.email` on a hidden field doesn't look right (anyone could modify that! I'm not sure what are you using that field for, but don't let the user change that). Are you using some gem for user authentication (like devise) or it's a custom password reset implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code example, you have:

`<%= form_for(@user, url: password_reset_path(params[:id]), method: :put) do |f| %>`

Is the plurality of `reset` incorrect?

`<%= form_for(@user, url: password_resets_path(params[:id]), method: :put) do |f| %>`

Comment: This was it, can't believe I didnt see it 
Thanks a lot this saved me so much time! :)